# How does spring manage enumerations?

Tags: java, spring, enumeration

```
//Can not add  @Component annotations, error
Public enum EArith {
   ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE
}

@Component
Public class Test{
  @Autowired
  EArith[] eAriths; // error
}
```

My idea is to let spring put on the EArith enumeration add, subtract, multiply and divide in the array, excuse me, how to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have Spring's @Component on enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802634/can-i-have-springs-component-on-enum)

Comment: You need to elaborate your question to get good answers.

Comment: Why would you want to auto-wire an enum array? What's the actual use case for this?