# Spring Boot cron job gets triggered before Spring Application is loaded in spite of using CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I am using Spring Boot's @Scheduled annotation to schedule a cron job that triggers every 5 seconds.
The cron job method is supposed to access some data which is initialized when the Spring Application is loaded.
However the job is triggered before the SpringApplication.run() is completed. How do I make sure that cron job is triggered only after Spring Application is loaded? Using a Thread.sleep() is definitely not good solution IMO.
Below is the code snippet.

```
MyWebApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages="CronJobPackage")
public class MyWebApplication implements CommandLineRunner, Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Starting MyWebApplication");

    SpringApplication.run(MyWebApplication.class).getEnvironment().getSystemProperties();

    System.out.println("Returned from MyWebApplication.run");

}
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

   initSomeData();

  }
}
/**********  CronJob.java **********************
@Component
public class CronJob{

   @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
   public void doSomething() {

   //access Data here which was initialized in initSomeData()

   }

}
```

Comment: You could set a variable after initSomeData() that you can check if the initialization is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place initData logic to bean initDataBean.

After that use `@DependsOn({"initDataBean"})`. It force spring to create `CronJob` after all required beans

Have a look at the code:

```
@Component
@DependsOn({"initDataBean"})
public class CronJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
    public void doSomething() {
        //access Data here which was initialized in initSomeData()
   }
}
```

Comment: Was not aware of @ Dependson. Thanks!. Here the initData is actually a enum (used to implement singleton class). I cannot use @ Bean for enum type. Is there any other alternative? Last option is to replace enum with singleton implementation the hard way

Comment: You could have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802634/can-i-have-springs-component-on-enum

Comment: This will accomplish.https://gitlab.com/johnjvester/jpa-spec-with-quartz